# How to check whether libwww-perl is installed or not in my server

Tags: perl, centos, libwww-perl

How to check whether libwww-perl is installed or not in my server.

And also tell me what is the use of libwwww-perl. How to remove this if we remove what are the things going to affect.

libwww-perl is connected with perl modules or lighttpd.

Answer (score 2):

> How to check whether libwww-perl is installed or not in my server

Trying to use something it provides is the simplest way.

If `perl -MLWP::UserAgent` throws an error, then it isn't installed.

> And also tell me what is the use of libwwww-perl

[Its manual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm) can do that more comprehensively than I can.

> How to remove this

That depends on how you installed it in the first place.

> if we remove what are the things going to affect.

Potentially: Many and diverse things (including admin scripts provided by your OS). Providing a comprehensive list isn't feasible.

> libwww-perl is connected with perl modules or lighttpd.

It provides Perl modules. They might be used by scripts that run via Lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

libwww-perl package should correspond to LWP::UserAgent Perl module. It is a pure-Perl implementation of HTTP user agent, as you might imagine it is used to retrieve documents via HTTP.
So if you're not running any scripts on your server that use HTTP, it is probably pretty safe to remove.